# How to use SSL certs with .p12 format with Traefik

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, traefik

In all [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/user-guide/examples/), it is mentioned to add .crt and .key to traefik.toml.

In my case, I just have a .p12 file, it is possible to use a .p12 with traefik?

Comment: Why don't you convert it ?

Comment: Why not convert the certificate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980370/how-to-convert-p12-to-crt-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with [differences](https://serverfault.com/a/9717/477518) between formats. Thanks to @sysadmin1138 for great explanation.

> PEM - Governed by RFCs, its used preferentially by open-source
> software. It can have a variety of extensions (.pem, .key, .cer,
> .cert, more)
>
> DER -
> The parent format of PEM. It's useful to think of it as a binary
> version of the base64-encoded PEM file. Not routinely used very much
> outside of Windows.
>
> .pkcs12 .pfx .p12 - Originally defined by RSA in the Public-Key
> Cryptography Standards (abbreviated PKCS), the "12" variant was
> originally enhanced by Microsoft, and later submitted as RFC 7292.
> This is a passworded container format that contains both public and
> private certificate pairs. Unlike .pem files, this container is fully
> encrypted.

The main info about .p12 - it is fully encrypted  and passworded container.

Take a quick look into [traefik certificate.go](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/424e2a9439f8f3b00d7f9f19ed1df3b6d3c8c570/pkg/tls/certificate.go)

Package `tls` use only [crypto/tls](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/) and [crypto/x509](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/).

```
package tls

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    ...    
)
```

Look at [crypto/x509: reading certificates from PKCS12 files](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10621) github issue:
There was a try to add `PKCS12` cert support into [crypto/x509](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/) but in the end it was not implemented.

As it was mentioned in comments, right way is to convert .p12.

Here is [example](https://serverfault.com/a/413836/477518) hot to achieve it (thank to @mulaz):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -nocerts -out filename.key

openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out filename.crt
```

And a source of the same: [Tips : Using openssl to extract private key ( .pem file) from .pfx (Personal Information Exchange)](https://sycure.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/tips-using-openssl-to-extract-private-key-pem-file-from-pfx-personal-information-exchange/)

Hope it helps!